# CoffeeScript Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm getting undefined objects resulting from the below code.

I get an error that note and notes is not defined.

```
@app = window.app ? {}

class Notes extends Backbone.Collection
model: app.Note
url: '/notes'


@app = window.app ? {}
@app.Notes = new Notes
# MODELS

class Note extends Backbone.Model

@app = window.app ? {}
@app.Note = new Note
#
jQuery ->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is code from three different files that you've pasted together. When you write `new Note`, you've got a scoping problem: There's no `Note` variable in the local scope, and no global with that name either.

You're already exporting `Notes` and `Note` by attaching them to the global `app` object. So you should be writing write

```
@app.Notes = new @app.Notes
```

and

```
@app.Note = new @app.Note
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using coffeescript and you are not paying attention to any indentation. Coffeescript works on indentation. Try this : -

```
@app = window.app ? {}

class Notes extends Backbone.Collection
  model: app.Note
  url: '/notes'

  @app = window.app ? {}
  @app.Notes = new Notes
# MODELS

class Note extends Backbone.Model
  @app = window.app ? {}
  @app.Note = new Note
#
jQuery ->
```

and i would really like you to put the code that can be understood properly , not some part of code. From this part only thing i could think of was about the indentation.

Comment: This wouldn't explain the error message. I suspect that the formatting in the question is messed up, but not the original code.